# wxPython -- Drag and Drop image between position-fixed containers, what is the suitable container?

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I am using wxPython for a board game. And want to drag chessman over positions.

What is the container I should use? Should I put image for chessman in its own panel or as button or somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a wx.Panel without any issues. There is a CustomDragAndDrop example in the wxPython demo that shows how to drag and drop images from one wx.Window to another. A wx.Panel is a type of wx.Window and I would think it would be better to use anyway. I would give that a try.

Comment: Thank you very much for making this clear. It's hard to decide which way to go